# nodejs using cheerio parsing xml returns empty CDATA

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, cdata, cheerio

I am using cheerio in nodejs to parse some rss feeds. I am grabbing all the items putting them into an array. I am using 3 test feeds, all of them have a "description" child element for each "item" element. In one of the feeds the whole "description" is wrapped as CDATA, and I cant get its value. Here is an abbreviated code snippet

```
//Open the xml document with cheerio
$ = cheerio.load(arrXmlDocs[i],{ ignoreWhitespace : true, xmlMode : true});

//Loop through every item
$('item').each(function(i, xmlItem){

    //array to hold each item being converted into an array
    var tempArray = [];

    //Loop through each child of <item>
    $(xmlItem).children().each(function(i, xmlItem){
        //Get the name 
        tempArray[$(this)[0].name] = $(this).text();
    }

}
```

As expected the two rss feeds that dont have CDATA give me an array like this

```
[
    [
        name: 'name of episode',
        description:'description of episode',
        pubdate: 'published date'
    ],
    [
        name: 'name of episode',
        description:'description of episode',
        pubdate: 'published date'
    ]
]
```

and the feed with the CDATA description looks like this

```
    [
        name: 'name of episode',
        pubdate: 'published date'
    ],
```

So my question is: Why is cheerio not returning values wrapped in CDATA / how can I make it return those values.

Comment: Can you make it more clear exactly what you are asking here?

Comment: updated to more clearly ask the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/fb55/node-htmlparser/issues/29) ([related](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio/issues/131)) with cheerio. It is unable to create a correct tree out of XML with `CDATA` in your case yet. I know this is a disappointing answer, it's WIP.

It is being worked on, meanwhile, you can remove `CDATA` with a Regular Expression.

```
arrXmlDocs[i].replace(/<!\[CDATA\[([\s\S]*?)\]\]>(?=\s*<)/gi, "$1");
```

Here is a link to an example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afk/y4bwothd/).

While this is not an ideal solution, it should suffice until they work this issue out.